# Read SharePoint List item using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am wondering if anyone could clarify my confusion on how to use JavaScript to read/filter SharePoint List items, please?
As a code example from MSDN:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185007(v=office.14).aspx

In the CAML query XML, what is the FieldRef field in SharePoint List? Is it defined column names/list properties?

When ClientContext object load collListItem, it has a (Include) parameter which includes a bunch of field/property names, what are they? Are they defined column names/list properties as well?

Is there anyway I can know what field names are, so I can use/filter the List?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The FieldRef is the internal field name of the column. Sometimes it's the same as the display name but as the display name can be changed you can't be certain of this. When creating new columns, I find it best to create them WithoutSpacesLikeThis and then replace the spaces once created. This makes it much easier to see what's happening when you're referencing them in code or in a URL etc. The same with Sites,Lists, Libraries etc.

The quickest way to find the internal name is to open the column as if you were going to edit it and then look in the URL and you will find the internal name there.

For example, the internal name of ApprovalStatus is at the end of the below URL after Field=. If the field has been created with a space in the name the space will be replaced by %20. E.g. Approval%20Status.

```
_layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7BE07BFB18-BBED-4A57-8988-6CAEB47FAA02%7D&Field=ApprovalStatus
```

Another way to see the field names would be to use the REST api. You can do this by adding `_api/web/lits/getbytitle('NameOfList')/items` to the end of the site collection URL. However, depending on the number of items you have in the list, it might return a lot of data.

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/app/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('NameOfList)/items
```

> When ClientContext object load collListItem, it has a (Include)
>   parameter which includes a bunch of field/property names, what are
>   they? Are they defined column names/list properties as well?

As far as this part of your question is concerned, can you provide some of the properties to give a better idea of what it is you're talking about, please?

Comment: I wasn't sure what the FileRef field is in the Include parameter of the load method: load(newsitems, "Include(ID, Title, PublishingExpirationDate, FileRef, NewsDate)");

Comment: I think the REST API helps me a lot to understand what fields are available in the List to be read/filtered. The only field I am not sure is the FileRef, not sure if it is an internal property of any SharePoint List.

Comment: According to the page linked below FileRef is the internal name for URL Path and it's a default field in a document library. I'm assuming this would be the direct URL for the file itself.

https://sharepointmalarkey.wordpress.com/2008/08/21/sharepoint-internal-field-names

I'm not sure if I should post the list here as it's pretty big.